# Node.js app showing favicon.ico path error

Tags: node.js

I have deployed a Node.js app to heroku but as I run it for first time, it works good but then some error logs come up which say npm error and favicon.ico error and then the server closes the connection. I am not getting any sort of help from their documentation. Please help me run it!!

Comment: Can you please share the details of the error in the question?

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Also please share your code you are using to run your application. This might give a lot of insight into the actual problem.

Comment: I am adding github repository beacuse there many files. [Github Repo](https://github.com/tyagivipul629/nodejs-project1)

Comment: Now the only problem seems to be the mysql server closing the connection each time 'auth' route is performed!! So the user cannot login!